# What does three.js's Matrix4.multiply() method do?

Tags: javascript, matrix, three.js, linear-algebra, matrix-multiplication

I'm learning [three.js](http://threejs.org/) and am trying to multiply two translation matrices together to get a single matrix that describes both translations:

```
| 1 0 0 -2 |   | 1 0 0 3 |
| 0 1 0  7 | * | 0 1 0 4 |
| 0 0 1  6 |   | 0 0 1 6 |
| 0 0 0  1 |   | 0 0 0 1 |
```

I was expecting the following matrix:

```
| 1 0 0  1 |   
| 0 1 0 11 | 
| 0 0 1 12 |   
| 0 0 0  1 |
```

But instead, I'm getting this matrix:

```
| 1  0  0  0 |   
| 0  1  0  0 | 
| 0  0  1  0 |   
| 1  11 12 1 |
```

I'm using three.js's `Matrix4.multiply()` method to do the multiplication:

```
var result = matrix1.multiply(matrix2);
```

[Here's a jsfiddle that shows this in action.](http://jsfiddle.net/NathanFriend/6wjnkwxb/)

[And here's a WolframAlpha query that gives the expected result.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%7B1%2C0%2C0%2C-2%7D%2C%7B0%2C1%2C0%2C7%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C1%2C6%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C0%2C1%7D%7D%20*%20%7B%7B1%2C0%2C0%2C3%7D%2C%7B0%2C1%2C0%2C4%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C1%2C6%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C0%2C1%7D%7D)

I'm obviously misunderstanding three.js's `Matrix4.multiply()` method.  What is this method doing and how can I instead achieve the expected behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in how you're iterating the matrix elements to print them. The [`.elements`](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Math/Matrix4) property returns the elements in [column-major order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order) (despite the constructor and `.set()` methods parameters being in row-major order!). So you should:

```
function logMatrix(matrix) {
    var e = matrix.elements;
    var $output = $('#output');
    $output.html(e[0] + ' ' + e[4] + ' ' + e[8] + ' ' + e[12] + '\n');
    $output.append(e[1] + ' ' + e[5] + ' ' + e[9] + ' ' + e[13] + '\n');
    $output.append(e[2] + ' ' + e[6] + ' ' + e[10] + ' ' + e[14] + '\n');
    $output.append(e[3] + ' ' + e[7] + ' ' + e[11] + ' ' + e[15] + '\n');
}
```

Also note that there was a typo in your code and you were printing `e[13]` twice...

Comment: Thanks - I just noticed the typo, too, and that was what was throwing me off - I couldn't figure out where that extra 11 was coming from.  Makes much more sense now that it's correct!